# Seamless memory-mapped files in C

Tags: c, linux, posix

I'm creating several programs in C that will have to communicate through files.

They will be using files because the communication will not be linear, i.e. program #5 could use a file that program #2 created.

The execution of these programs will be linear (serial).

There will be a single control program which manages the execution of these cascading programs. This program will be the one creating the files, and should only pass file names to the programs

Since disk I/O is slow (lets assume the OS doesn't cache these operations), I would need to use memory-mapped files.

However, the requirement is that the control program can seamlessly switch between regular and memory-mapped files - which means that the cascading programs will have to be unaware of whether they're writing/reading to/from a memory-mapped file or a regular one.

**How can I create a file, which presents itself to the rest of the system as a normal file (has a place in the FS hierarchy, a file name, can be read and written), but is in fact in memory and not on the disk?**

Comment: Why memory mapped files, this sounds more like a job for a series of pipes. The control program creates a set of pipes, and the other programs uses these as the standard output and input. Then the program can just write to/read from `stdout` and `stdin`. Just like using pipes to chain a set of terminal programs.

Comment: Instead of having each program read from a file, you can instead decide to have them read from stdin. Then to run the programs you simply do `./prog1 | prog2 | prog3 ...` etc

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Two reasons. First, an output of the program might be multiple files, not just one. Second, this isn't really a cascade of programs: program #5 could use the file that program #2 created.

Comment: Then use a special command line option (many use a plain dash like `-`) to indicate that input/output should be from/to stain/stdout. If the special command line options is not present, then use normal files.

Comment: Sorry, I gave you the wrong reason, please read my edited comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology you're using here is a little weird - memory-mapping is a way of accessing a file (any file), not a separate type of file from one that's stored on disk.

That being said, if you want to have some of your files written out to disk and some not, the easiest way to do that would be to store them in an in-memory filesystem, such as `tmpfs`. There is usually one of these mounted at `/dev/shm` on most Linux systems.

Comment: `tmpfs` is the thing I've been looking for, it seems, thanks.